# Pushing to array in asynchonous map

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, asynchronous

I know this question has already been asked but i just can't manage to make this right. Tried using promises but to no avail. When console logging req.user items is still an empty array. I know I should use promises but I am having trouble implementing it. Help appreciated

```
app.get('/cart',checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    if(req.user.cart.length > 0){
        req.user.items = []
       
        req.user.cart.map(async (item) => {
            var itemDescription = await productsModel.findOne({id: item.itemId})
            req.user.items.push(itemDescription)
        });
        
        console.log(req.user)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's empty it's because you don't await for all the async functions in the map to finish. Try this:

```
await Promise.all(req.user.cart.map(async (item) => {
  var itemDescription = await productsModel.findOne({id: item.itemId})
  req.user.items.push(itemDescription)
}));
```

Note as @jfriend00 has commented this implementation will not guarantee the order of items in req.user.items.

Because you are already using map it's just simpler to do the following and it also guarantees the order of items:

```
req.user.items = await Promise.all(req.user.cart.map(async (item) => {
  var itemDescription = await productsModel.findOne({id: item.itemId})
  return itemDescription;
}));
```

Comment: Note that `req.user.items` in your first implementation will not be in a defined order because you're running lots of `await productsModel.findOne({id: item.itemId})` in parallel and it's just a race to see which ones finish first and get pushed into the array first.  Your  second implementation uses `Promise.all()` to maintain order.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are absolutely correct, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`.map()` is not promise-aware.  It doesn't pay any attention to the promise that your `async` callback function returns.  So, as soon as you hit the `await productsModel.findOne(...)`, that `async` function returns an unfulfilled promise and the `.map()` advances to the next iteration of the loop.

There are many different ways to solve this.  If you want to use `.map()`, then you need to pay attention to the promise that your callback is returned like this:

```
app.get('/cart', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.cart.length > 0) {

        req.user.items = await Promise.all(req.user.cart.map((item) => {
            return productsModel.findOne({ id: item.itemId });
        }));

        console.log(req.user)
    }
});
```

The above implementation will attempt to run all the database lookups in parallel.

---

A somewhat simpler implementation just uses a plain `for` loop and runs the database lookups one at a time:

```
app.get('/cart', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.cart.length > 0) {
        req.user.items = [];

        for (let item of req.user.cart) {
            req.user.items.push(await productsModel.findOne({ id: item.itemId }));
        }

        console.log(req.user)
    }
});
```

Comment: You explained it really well.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the array is still empty because the callback in the map function works asynchronously, hence you need to wait while the code will complete. Because map function returns array of promises, they all need to be settled using Promise.all:

```
app.get('/cart', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.cart.length > 0) {
        req.user.items = []

        const promises = req.user.cart.map(async (item) => {
            var itemDescription = await productsModel.findOne({ id: item.itemId })
            req.user.items.push(itemDescription)
        });

        await Promise.all(promises);

        console.log(req.user)
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you can replace map function with for loop:

```
app.get('/cart', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.cart.length > 0) {
        req.user.items = []

        for (const item of req.user.cart) {
            var itemDescription = await productsModel.findOne({ id: item.itemId })
            req.user.items.push(itemDescription)
        }

        console.log(req.user)
    }
});
```